# How to write an If/ Else statement in Cypress for finding a button?

Tags: cypress

I have a page that can hold 25 items and when there are more than 25, then it goes onto the next page, how can I write an if statement to first check if the ‘Next Page Button’ is enabled/ visible and if it is visible/enabled then to click on it and if it is not visible, then to find the item on the current page it is on?

Comment: From your wording it sounds like the item you seek will always be on the last page if there are more than one page. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

If the Next Page button is enabled/disabled then you can do:

```js
cy.get('next-page-button').then(($btn) => {
  if ($btn.is(':enabled')) {
    cy.wrap($btn).click() //Click on the next page button
  } else {
    //Do something when the button is disabled
  }
})
```

If the Next Page button exists/Doesn't exists:

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find('next-page-button').length > 0) {
    cy.get('next-page-button').click() //Button exists and click on the button
  } else {
    //Do something when the button doesn't exist
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wait for the page to refresh each time the button is clicked.

If you have an element that indicates the page number, use that. If not you will need to add a hard wait.

```js
const clickUntilDisabled = ($button, page = 1) => {

  if (page > 100) return    // make sure it does not keep clicking forever

  if ($button.is(':enabled') && $button.is(':visible')) {
    $button.click()

    // page refeshes
    cy.contains(`Page ${++page}`)    // check the page indicator
    // or cy.wait(500)                             

    clickUntilDisabled($button, page)   // click again
  } 
}

cy.contains('button', 'Next Page Button')
  .then(clickUntilDisabled)
  .then(() => {
    // test item here
  })
```